# Process Cube in SSAS

Tags: ssas

I have a snowflake model, when I render this cube to the SSAS server, the Product_Class table is taken, it is in Dimensions, but it doesn't appear when I click on "Cube Name" and then "Browser"

[image]

I wonder what I'm doing wrong,

Tks,
_Keny

Comment: Why do you have two arrows between the Fact, and Dim Product?

Comment: What is the output of this query in SSMS `Select Product_Category, Sum (Unit_Sales) NumSales From Sales_Fact_1998 F Inner Join Product P On F.Product_Id = P.ProductId Inner Join Product_Class PC on P.Product_Class_Id = PC.Product_Class_Id Group By Product_Category`

Comment: Raj More, The result was:  Product_Category = "Name Caregory" , NumSales = 58487276

Comment: I don't know why we have 2 relationships, the other DW team sent me like this,
Is it wrong, can't I have two relationship?